# Add / remove a class to / from specific list items in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, list, animation, mapping

I have a react webpage which renders a list of links from an array that lives inside a local database. I want to show link hints when I hover over each link (list item).

Currently, when I hover over a list item (a link on my webpage), all the link hints from other links are shown. I only want the one that I hover over to show the hint. How can I achieve this effect?

--

**The problem in action:**

[image: GIF showing the issue]

--

**React Code:**

```
function Works() {
  const [hoverHint, setHoverHint] = useState(false);

  function showHoverHint() {
    setHoverHint(true);
  }
  function hideHoverHint() {
    setHoverHint(false);
  }

  const linkMaps = {
    website: <Globe fill="#aaa" size={20} />,
    github: <GitHub fill="#aaa" size={20} />,
    gitlab: <GitLab fill="#aaa" size={20} />,
    apk: <Android fill="#aaa" size={20} />,
    youtube: <YouTube fill="#aaa" size={20} />
  };

  return(
    <ul className="work-links">
      {work.links.map(link => (
        <li>
          <span
            className={
              hoverHint ? 'before show-hint' : 'before hide-hint'
            }
          >
            {link.text}
          </span>
          <a
            href={link.url}
            target="_blank"
            rel="noopener noreferrer"
            onMouseOver={showHoverHint}
            onMouseOut={hideHoverHint}
          >
            {linkMaps[link.type]}
          </a>
          <span
            className={
              hoverHint ? 'after show-hint' : 'after hide-hint'
            }
          >
            {link.text}
          </span>
        </li>
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
}
```

**CSS Code:**

```
.work-links {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin-top: 0.3em;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

.work-links svg {
  transition: 0.15s;
}

.work-links a {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0.4em 0.4em 0;
  margin-bottom: 0.8em;
  background-color: #eee;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transition: 0.15s;
  z-index: 1;
}

.work-links a:hover {
  background-color: #333;
}

.work-links a:hover svg {
  fill: #eee;
}

.work-card-container:nth-child(odd) .work-links {
  right: -11em;
  align-items: flex-start;
}
.work-card-container:nth-child(even) .work-links {
  left: -11em;
  align-items: flex-end;
}

.work-card-container:nth-child(odd) .before {
  display: none;
}
.work-card-container:nth-child(even) .before {
  right: 0.5em;
  transition: 0.1s;
}
.work-card-container:nth-child(even) .after {
  display: none;
}
.work-card-container:nth-child(odd) .after {
  left: 0.5em;
  transition: 0.2s;
}

.hide-hint {
  opacity: 0;
}
.work-card-container:nth-child(even) .hide-hint {
  transform: translateX(50%);
}
.work-card-container:nth-child(odd) .hide-hint {
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}

.show-hint {
  transform: translateX(0);
  opacity: 1;
}

.work-links > li {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.work-links span {
  position: relative;
  top: -0.5em;
  color: #888;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to trigger the hover state based on a unique identifier, rather than a shared state value.

Here's one approach that comes to mind:

```
const [selectedLink, setSelectedLink] = React.useState(null)

<ul className="work-links">
  {work.links.map(link => (
    <li>
      <span
        className={
          hoverHint ? 'before show-hint' : 'before hide-hint'
        }
      >
        {link.text}
      </span>
      <a
        href={link.url}
        target="_blank"
        rel="noopener noreferrer"
        // Use the URL as a unique identifier
        onMouseOver={() => setSelectedLink(link.url)}
        // Set to null on mouseout
        onMouseOut={() => setSelectedLink(null)}
      >
        {linkMaps[link.type]}
      </a>
      <span
        className={
          selectedLink === link.url ? 'after show-hint' : 'after hide-hint'
        }
      >
        {link.text}
      </span>
    </li>
  ))}
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. I updated my question and added statements before the 'return' in my react function for reference. 

As for your answer, how should I then use the 'link.url' which is inside 'selectedLink' state to add / remove either 'show-hint' or 'hide-hint' classes?

Comment: Oops! Updated my answer, haha. Yeah, you want to compare `selectedLink` to the iterated `link.url` property to trigger classes.